# Why does hovering the mouse over a combobox make my tabpage re-paint itself?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls, paint, tabpage

I have a tabpage. And I have a combobox in it.
When I hover my mouse over it, my tabpage's paint function runs.
Why?

The Combobox has no functions handled. It is just a Combobox.
I move the combobox out of the tabpage, and now the tabpage won't paint when I hover my mouse over the combobox. Weird..

Comment: This couldn't possibly be relevant to anything other than idle curiosity. You should never have code in the `Paint` event handler method that you don't expect to get executed repeatedly, non-deterministically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to a TabPage, the same thing happens when you put the combo on a form.  It is affected by visual styles, the container paint requests stop when you turn that off.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the rounded corners you get when the DropDown property is set to DropDownList, the combo glows on a mouse hover.  With it probably asking the container control to draw the pixels in the corner.  Explaining it for DropDown = DropDown is harder.

Same thing happens with a Button, the container control paint is documented in the Reference Source to support transparency effects.  Even if the button doesn't have anything transparent.  Visual styles is less than optimized like this, perhaps.  It is otherwise very similar to what WPF does.  Long story short, this is normal.